# Get all items from the parent table, but switch out the foreign key with a column from the child table

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have two tables in mysql and I'm trying to make a query call. In the Item table, the tid is a foreign key, but in the query call, I want to get all the information in the Items table, but instead of getting the tid, I want to get the name of the Types the tid refers to. What is the proper query call here?

```
|_______Items______|      |________Types______|
| id {PK}          |      | tid {PK}          |
| name             |      | name              |
| description      |      | description       |
| tid {fk}         |      |                   |
```

```js
app.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
  var content = {};
  mysql.pool.query('SELECT * FROM Items WHERE id=?', [req.query.id],
    function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
        return;
      }
      content.results = JSON.stringify(rows);
      res.send(content.results);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct query should be:

```
mysql.pool.query('SELECT * FROM Items INNER JOIN Types on Types.tid = Items.tid WHERE Items.id=?', [req.query.id],
```

This will return all the fields from both tables, but only show the row from Types where the `tid` is used in the row of Items which has the `id` passed in `req.query.id`

This is done using a SQL `INNER JOIN` - if you're not familiar with this way of joining tables, it's quite fundamental to SQL and you should study it.

P.S. If you want just a specific selection of columns from the two tables (as hinted at in the question), you can write it like this, for instance:

```
mysql.pool.query('SELECT Items.id, Items.name, Items.description, Types.name FROM Items INNER JOIN Types on Types.tid = Items.tid WHERE Items.id=?', [req.query.id],
```

Comment: This just returns the Types table with no information from the Items table.

As mentioned above, I'm trying to return all data from the Items table but change the tid to the name from the Types table

Comment: In the question you said, " I want to get the name of the Types", so that's what I did :-). If you want all the fields from both fields just change it to `SELECT *`. Or if you want specific fields from each table, list them explicitly e.g. `SELECT Types.name, Items.name, Items.description` or whatever you need

Comment: Above I've stated:
"I want to get all the information in the Items table, but instead of getting the tid, I want to get the name of the Types the tid refers to"

Comment: Ok well sorry, I missed that part, but anyway `SELECT *` is adequate (I've updated the answer to use that instead) and will get all of it. Or, like I said you can specify just the ones you want. It's not really the important part - the use of the JOIN is the main point of the answer. Do you understand how to specify fields in a SQL SELECT statement?

Comment: ... Your edition will return ALL information from BOTH tables.

Comment: Yes. I've explained that it's _adequate_. If you want some specific fields, specify them in the way I showed in my comment above. Did you understand that? You didn't say exactly what fields you want, but can we assume it's `id`, `name` and `description` from `Items`, and just `name` from `Types`? That's how I'd interpret your description of the requirement. Or do you want `tid` as well? It's not 100% clear.

Comment: id, name, description from Items but name that is associated with the tid from the Types WITHOUT explicitly calling each individual column of the table because as you see in the query above, the parameter that is passed is the id for the Items tables.

Comment: "without explicitly calling each individual column of the table", not really sure exactly what you mean by that, or how you think it has a relationship to passing the Item ID? What you list in the SELECT has no bearing on what you put in the WHERE, or vice versa. The columns available are those from the tables listed in the FROM. Anyway if you don't want all the columns in the output, you have to explicitly list the columns you want. So either you make a list, or you use *. It's up to you. Maybe you need to get some of the basic SQL concepts straight in your head, I'm not sure.

Comment: I've added an alternative query syntax to the answer